# How to get around 'Input line too long' error when running commands from asp

Tags: c#, windows, shell

In my app I'm running a terminal command from asp script, which runs PhantomJs with some parameters given and logs the result. Unfortunately because I'm passing paths to files the whole command becomes too long for the retarded Windows terminal and I'm getting `input line too long` error. What makes it even more strange is that the limit was supposed to be 2/8k and I've got only around 350 chars. Is there also a limit for the length of single parameter ?

This is my code with a sample command :

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo phantomProcess = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
phantomProcess.FileName = "cmd";
```

`string command = "/c \"phantomjs 'K:\\LAMP\\www\\2.x\\examples\\ASP.NET MVC2 demo\\ASP.NET MVC\\render.js' 'K:\\LAMP\\www\\2.x\\examples\\ASP.NET MVC2 demo\\ASP.NET MVC\\exportHtml-1570662045.html|K:\\LAMP\\www\\2.x\\examples\\ASP.NET MVC2 demo\\ASP.NET MVC\\exportHtml-1570642318.html|K:\\LAMP\\www\\2.x\\examples\\ASP.NET MVC2 demo\\ASP.NET MVC\\exportHtml-1570648254.html|K:\\LAMP\\www\\2.x\\examples\\ASP.NET MVC2 demo\\ASP.NET MVC\\exportHtml-1570696111.html|K:\\LAMP\\www\\2.x\\examples\\ASP.NET MVC2 demo\\ASP.NET MVC\\exportHtml-1570696111.html|K:\\LAMP\\www\\2.x\\examples\\ASP.NET MVC2 demo\\ASP.NET MVC\\exportHtml-1570669151.html|K:\\LAMP\\www\\2.x\\examples\\ASP.NET MVC2 demo\\ASP.NET MVC\\exportHtml-1570669151.html|K:\\LAMP\\www\\2.x\\examples\\ASP.NET MVC2 demo\\ASP.NET MVC\\exportHtml-1570678096.html'\"";`

```
phantomProcess.Arguments = command;
System.IO.StreamReader sOut = proc.StandardOutput;
phantomOut = sOut.ReadToEnd().Trim();
proc.WaitForExit();
sOut.Close();
```

Is there any way to get around this error, some windows-specific tricks ? I've seen some solutions using environment variables but assigning long string to a variable looks to be broken in the very same way. Please correct me if the tags are wrong.

---

EDIT

I've found some information from MS regarding this 'feature' : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473 . They suggest putting params to a text file and then running the desired app with this filename passed as a parameter. I've tried this approach but it looks like the whole terminal freezes after I run it like this.

Comment: Can you set the current directory of the new process? If all the files are in the same folder (as they seem to be from your example) you could set the CD to that folder and then would only need to pass the names of the files rather than the full paths.

Comment: Putting params in a text-file sounds like the way to go. Sounds like there is some kind of outside-condition stopping this. Have you verified that you have the necessary access-rights to read them from a file, for instance? Have you checked if there could be any restrictions on such things when running scripts from ASP?